# showing records from two sql table alternatively

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

In my asp.net page, There are some locations in a `dropdownlist`.
For each Location, there are many employees stored in a `sql server table EmpDetails`, reference key is *LocId*.
Each employee have some entries that are stored in another table *EmpEntries*. 

The reference key is *EmpId*. 
When user select any location, the display should be like this:

```
1st Employee record details from EmpDetails table,
```

below it the entries belong to this employee from EmpEntries table.

 Then the 2nd employee and its entries,... till the last employee for that location.
What databound controls required and what would be the corresponding sql query ?

Comment: here is a link which may help you http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189621/Creating-an-expandable-master-details-table-jQuery

Comment: Thanks, not familiar with MVC, rather asp.net webform example will be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a sql select query similar to this....

```
select * from EmployeeDetails ed
left join EmployeeEntries ee on ee.EmpId = ed.EmpId
```

Note that this query will return all entries for each employee and each record will have the employee details as well. That means the employee details will be repeated for each entry the have in the EmployeeEntries table
Then use a web server control that handles grouping such as the ListView, for more info, read this....

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.groups(v=vs.110).aspx

Which will produce something similar to this...

https://web.archive.org/web/20161106210140/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/images/ListView/05.01.png

Your question is too abstract and there's a lot to cover but if you still don't get how to achieve this, then read this tutorial...

https://web.archive.org/web/20210301194237/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091708-1.aspx

Hope it helps,
Leo.

Comment: Thanks, i got the result :)